# Can an Excel object reference the Visio page it's on?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I have an Excel table object that is on my Visio project. The table is on the first page and is an index of the following pages. I am trying to write a formula in the cells that will reference the names of each page in my Visio Project. That way I can create a new page and the page will show up on the excel index as say (panel discussion page 3) How can I do this in Microsoft Visio 2013?

Comment: I figured out how to do this. I used left(thisdocument.pages(i).OLEObjects(a).ProgID, 5) = "excel"

Comment: then i used   set theExcelTable = thisdocument.pages(i).OLEObjects(a).Object.Application then I used theExcelTable.WorkBooks(1).worksheets(1).range("A1") = "joe"